# Is there a way to skip the Bochs debug command line?

Tags: debugging, bochs

I have the debug-enabled version of bochs. Although I occasionally need debug mode, most of the time, I want to launch bochs right from the terminal without stopping to press "c" on the debug command line.  Is there a setting that will do this (that doesn't require me to install two different versions of bochs)?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following

- Start bochs
- Go through the menu setup until you get a booting system
- Stop bochs
- Start bochs again
- there should be a menu option to "Dump options to file"
- dump the options to file
- remember the filename, for example say we use bochs9.cfg
- exit bochs

Now create a file with the letter c followed by a newline, name it something like silly.txt

Now run bochs like this:

```
 bochs -qf ./bochs9.cfg -rc ./silly.txt
```

- **-qf** will force bochs to skip the menus and use your options file
- **-rc** will force bochs to fake typing the contents of silly.txt, which in this case is 'c' + newline, to make it run

This will allow you to boot Bochs into an OS directly from the commandline. Tested with [Svardos](http://svardos.org) bootdisk.

See also this [Sourceforge Discussion](https://sourceforge.net/p/bochs/mailman/bochs-developers/thread/01a201d1a146%24249da970%246dd8fc50%24%40gmail.com/)

Answer (score -2):

You can use `-q` option to skip debugger prompt in the beginning.

`bochs -q`

Comment: this does not work. bochs 2.6.11 on linux. workaround is to dump options from the menu to a file,  then run bochs -qf configfile    however this still leaves you at debug prompt having to type 'c'